# Getting "TypeError: undefined is not an object" in an Expo React Native project when trying to create a custom "react-hook-form" input component

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, undefined, react-hook-form

I'm trying to create a reusable component and use it instead of the default `TextInput` component in all of our screens. Inside this new `CustomTextInput.js` component, I'm exporting the main configurable component as default which is wrapped in a `Controller` component provided by the [`react-hook-form`](https://react-hook-form.com/api) library. I'm then supposed to pass the `control` config object from the parent component whenever I create an instance of the `CustomTextInput` component.

Besides the default export, I'm also exporting some pre-configured variations of that `CustomTextInput` component. I was successful with exporting and using the `EmailInput` and `PasswordInput` configurations, but I'm encountering `ref` and `revalidation` errors whenever I try to use my `CalendarInput` and `LocationInput` components. Though I'm able to create them manually by passing all the configurations through the main component from the default export of `CustomTextInput.js`.

To be more specific I'm getting this error message for when I try to display either `CalendarInput` or `LocationInput`:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref21$reValidateMode.isReValidateOnBlur')
```

I reproduced the error in an Expo Snack and the essential parts of **the code can be found at this URL**:
https://snack.expo.io/@sepsol/custom-text-input-error

How can I bypass this error and resolve this issue by successfully displaying `CalendarInput` and `LocationInput` exported from `CustomTextInput.js` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@leapful](https://github.com/leapful) I was able to solve the problem. It was a typo on my end:

The CalendarInput and LocationInput are currently using wrong props parameter. It should be:

```
export function CalendarInput({ control, ... }) {}
```

instead of

```
export function CalendarInput(control, ...)
```